# What is OrientDB's indexing scheme?

Tags: orientdb

Just like the question says. Are there explicit indexes you need to add your documents into? Or is it automatic secondary indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are both kinds of indexes:

- automatic, created against the schema and populated automatically. This is very close to what RDBMS offers
- manual, created and populated manually using Java API, HTTP REST protocol or plain SQL using "index:" as prefix instead of the class name.

For more information look at: http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/Indexes

Comment: BTW, can it be used for 10000s of indexes for a completely schemaless DB? Or for an extremely large number of classes? I am thinking on the lines of indexes in Elastic search (or MongoDB secondary indexes)

Comment: Course you can, but performance change based on number of indexes used like any DBMS

Comment: Thanks, and I will follow up with a more detailed question on your support site